# Custom Python package is not accessible installed via Pip

Tags: python, pip, python-module, python-packaging

I am writing a Python package and this is my file structure. simple_eda is main folder in which I have **init** file and my code file. In my code file I have Class SimpleEDA which does all the work. to import I want to use

```
import SimpleEDA or from simple_eda import SimpleEDA
```

My init file is empty.

- simple_eda

  .**init**.py

  .simple_eda.py
- tests
- setup.py
- README.md
- LICENSE

I have used this command to build whl for my simple_eda. I have used this command in the main directory where setup.py file is located.

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

This created whl file and tar.gz file successfully in dist folder. So I used

pip install simple_eda.whl

and the package gets installed. so I write python in my terminal to activate Python. I can import my package user

```
from simple_eda.simple_eda import SimpleEDA
```

but If I try to do this in Jupyter notebooks, it gives me error.

```
 from simple_eda.simple_eda import SimpleEDA
```

Here is my setup.py file code.

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="simple_eda", 
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Muhammad Shahid Sharif",
    author_email="chshahidhamdam@gmail.com",
    description="A wrapper around Pandas to perform Simple EDA with less code.",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="my git link here",
    packages=['simple_eda'],
    install_requires = ['matplotlib==3.0.3','nltk==3.4.5',
'numpy==1.17.2',
'numpydoc==0.9.1',
'pandas==0.25.1',
'scikit-image==0.15.0',
'scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1',
'scipy==1.4.1',
'seaborn==0.9.0',
'spacy==2.2.3',
'spacy-langdetect==0.1.2',
'spacy-readability==1.3.0',
'textblob==0.15.3'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.5',
)
```

I want to import my package like

```
import SimpleEDA or from simple_eda import SimpleEDA
```

Comment: I have tried it running from Documents directory and home directory, its working fine from both

Comment: its also working from directories in documents directory,

Comment: also running in Desktop

Comment: jupyter notebook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217165/discussion-between-shahid-hamdam-and-0-0).

Comment: Okay
No module named jupyter
its giving this error
I am in a conda venv

Comment: /snap/bin/jupyter

/home/shahid/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_2/bin/python3

Comment: I am using linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that OP has multiple conda environments and that the package was installed in one python environment, but jupyter notebook does not have access to that environment.

To use jupyter notebook with multiple conda environments, the recommended practice is to install `nb_conda_kernels` in the base environment and then install `ipykernel` (or other language kernel) in every environment that should be usable in jupyter notebook.

```
conda install -n base nb_conda_kernels
conda install -n MYENV ipykernel
jupyter-notebook  # Run this from the base environment
```

Then, navigate to your jupyter notebook, open it up, choose the kernel that corresponds to the conda environment you want to use, and run your notebook.

Also, to install the custom pip package in a certain conda environment, OP should be explicit with their commands. For example, use `python -m pip` instead of the `pip` wrapper.

```
conda activate MYENV  # or source activate MYENV
python -m pip install MYPACKAGE.whl
```

In the OP's case, they should install `ipykernel` in whichever environment has their custom package, and then when using jupyter notebook, they should use that environment's kernel.

Related: https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/342#issuecomment-382837602

Comment: it started working. Thank you. I have one more question. How I can change the way I import my package? currenty I import it like that. The way I want to is in question
from simple_eda.simple_eda import SimpleEDA

Comment: first simple_eda is package name, second simple_eda is filename and SimpleEDA is my main Class in that file.

Comment: Great. If this answered your question, please select the green checkmark to mark it as the answer. As for your second question, you can add `from simple_eda.simple_eda import SimpleEDA` to `simple_eda/__init__.py`.

Comment: so How I can import it then? import simple_eda?

Comment: Then you could use `from simple_eda import SimpleEDA`

Comment: can I make it import SimpleEDA somehow?

Comment: You would have to change your package name for that and use `__main__.py`, but I can't imagine why this would be necessary

Comment: Yeah I also think that :D. Thank you so much accepting your answer

Comment: do you know how I can make it pip install simpleEDA? I want it to be on pypi index.

Comment: Refer to the python packaging documentation. For the package name, look at the `name` argument in your setup script. https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#name

Comment: Does using `nb_conda_kernels` and `ipykernel` also work when using multiple Python versions in various environments? E.g., Python 3.7 in one env, 3.8 in another.

Comment: The `pip` wrapper should be fine, unless Conda messes that up. I.e., `pip` should correspond to the relevant `python` inside a Conda environment.

Comment: @00 - yes `nb_conda_kernels` and `ipykernel` work with any python version. You can also use it with R and other language kernels. The `python -m pip` syntax is still better in my opinion because it's more explicit, but conda shouldn't mess that up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in a Conda environment, it appears you have not installed Jupyter for that environment. Instead, the `jupyter` executable you are running is probably a globally installed one, while your home-grown package is installed locally (inside the Conda environment) with `pip`. Note the different paths for the two executables:

- Jupyter: `/snap/bin/jupyter`
- python3: `$HOME/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_2/bin/python3`

Thus, simply install Jupyter for your Conda environment, either with

```
conda install jupyter
```

or

```
pip install jupyter
```

Side note: since you are in a Conda environment, you should be able to simply use `python` instead of `python3`. One is just aliased to the other. This may not work outside your environment, if you are on an OS where `python` is still Python 2.

Comment: To add to this, when using jupyter in multiple conda environments, I prefer to install `nb_conda_kernels` in the base environment, and then `ipykernel` in each environment that should be accessible in jupyter. Then when you start jupyter notebook, you will have the option of changing kernels to your different environments.

Comment: installed jupyter using pip install jupyter and this is new path 
 {/home/shahid/anaconda3/envs/eda_test_2/bin/jupyter
}
but I am still getting same error